# Variable reference between two class and unknow type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ref

I have my `MainViewModel`, who contains all my bindings. Especially the binding of my `listView` (Multiple `listView` with different types). And I want to create a class who gonna contain the binding variable like (`ItemSeleted`, `ItemIndexSelected`, `ItemSource`). So I wrote this:

```
public class ListViewContener<T>
    {
        public T ItemSelected { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<T> ItemSourceList { get; set; }
        public int ItemIndexSelected { get; set; }

        public void SetItem(ref T itemSelected, ref ObservableCollection<T> itemSourceList, ref int itemIndexSelected)
        {
            this.ItemSelected = itemSelected;
            this.ItemSourceList = itemSourceList;
            this.ItemIndexSelected = itemIndexSelected;
        }

        public void ToPrevious(MediaElement mediaElement, ImageSource imageSource)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ItemIndexSelected);
            if (ItemIndexSelected - 1 >= 0)
            {
                ItemIndexSelected -= 1;
                dynamic dynSelected = ItemSelected;
                ItemSelected = ItemSourceList[ItemIndexSelected];
                mediaElement.Source = new Uri(dynSelected.Path);
                mediaElement.Play();
                imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Ressources/play.png", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
    }
```

My first question is :

- Can i create a constructor like that `public ListViewContener<T>(ref T item ...)`
- Can i store the reference of variable in my class like that `this.ItemSelected = itemSelected;`

In my `MainViewModel` I call the function `SetItem(...)` like that:

```
this._musiqueList.SetItem(ref _selectedItemListMusique, ref _itemSourceListMusique, ref _itemIndexSelectedM);
```

Example binding:

```
private MusicDB _selectedItemListMusique;
public MusicDB SelectedItemListMusique
        {
            get { return _selectedItemListMusique; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItemListMusique = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItemListView");
            }
        }
```